# A point electric charge in an angle sector: does the Green's function expansion simplify to the method of images if the angle is right?

Tags: electrostatics, mathematical-physics, greens-functions, method-of-images

Suppose that you're doing electrostatics in two dimensions (or, equivalently, in 3D with translation invariance along $z$) and you're studying the response to a point charge in an angle sector of opening angle $\alpha$, i.e. in the domain
$$
\mathcal D=\{(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))\in\mathbb R^2:0<\theta<\alpha\},
$$
under Dirichlet boundary conditions, i.e. between two conducting planes at dihedral angle $\alpha$.

Now, if you're actually faced with such a problem, the natural response is to say "ah, yeah, you can probably get the Green's function of the problem in terms of some expansion in terms of fractional-order Bessel functions something something something", and nobody can really remember the details, but luckily we have Jackson's *Classical Electrodynamics*, which informs us in §2.11 and in problem 2.25 that the Green's function for the problem is
\begin{align}
G(\mathbf r,\mathbf r') 
= 4 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n \frac{r_<^{n\pi/\alpha}}{r_>^{n\pi/\alpha}} 
\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{\alpha}\theta \right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{\alpha}\theta' \right),
\tag 1
\end{align}
satisfying $\nabla^2_\mathbf r G(\mathbf r,\mathbf r') = \delta(\mathbf r-\mathbf r')$ (up to signs and factors of $\pi$), where the arbitrary-real-number nature of the corner angle $\alpha$ manifests itself in the non-integer powers of the radii involved in the expansion.

---

On the other hand, for some special angles $\alpha$ of the form $\alpha = \pi/k$, where $k$ is an integer, one can just ditch all of that and simply use the [method of image charges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_images), by judiciously planting copies of our source charge at angles between $\alpha$ and $2\pi$ in such a way that the potential vanishes at the boundary of $\partial \mathcal D$ like it needs to, giving us the Green function in the form
$$
G(\mathbf r,\mathbf r') 
=\sum_{i}q_i\ln(\|\mathbf r- \mathbf r_i\|)
\tag 2
$$
where one of the $\mathbf r_i$ is $\mathbf r'$ and the rest are image charges.

---

OK, so after all that setup, here's my question: is it possible to directly reduce the general result in $(1)$ to the method-of-images result in $(2)$ through some means or another? Intuitively, it feels like that should be the case (though there's no promises that it'd be pretty), because $(1)$ contains all the information about the problem's solution and it should be possible to whittle it down to simpler versions where those exist; more prosaically, when $\alpha=\pi/k$ those exponents now read $r^{n\pi/\alpha} = r^{nk}$, which looks rather more manageable.

Along these lines, Jackson does add one tack to that problem 2.25, saying

> (b) By means of complex-variable techniques or other means, show that the series can be summed to give a closed  form,
>   $$
> G(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r}') 
> =
> \ln\left[\frac{
> r^{2\pi/\alpha}+r'^{2\pi/\alpha}-2(rr')^{\pi/\alpha}\cos(\pi(\theta+\theta')/\alpha)
> }{
> r^{2\pi/\alpha}+r'^{2\pi/\alpha}-2(rr')^{\pi/\alpha}\cos(\pi(\theta-\theta')/\alpha)
> }\right],
> $$

which looks like a step in the right direction, but (i) I can't fully see how you'd sum that series, and more importantly (ii) I'm not fully sure how you'd reduce that simplified series to the method-of-images solution.

So: is this possible? and if so, how? Also, a bit more ambitiously: does that still hold in 3D, where the Green's function goes up into Bessel expansions but the method of images still works?

Answer (score 3):

For Question (i), note that
$$
\sin \left( \frac{n \pi}{\alpha} \theta \right) \sin \left( \frac{n \pi}{\alpha} \theta' \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \cos \left(\frac{n \pi}{\alpha} (\theta - \theta') \right) - \cos \left(\frac{n \pi}{\alpha} (\theta + \theta') \right)\right] \\
= \frac{1}{2} \Re \left[ e^{n \pi i (\theta - \theta')/\alpha} - e^{n \pi i (\theta + \theta')/\alpha} \right]
$$
and so
$$
G(\mathbf r,\mathbf r') = 2 \Re \left\{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n \left[\left(\frac{r_<}{r_>} e^{i (\theta - \theta')}\right)^{n\pi/\alpha}
 - \left(\frac{r_<}{r_>} e^{i (\theta + \theta')}\right)^{n\pi/\alpha} \right]\right\}
$$
The summation can now be seen to be equivalent to two power series for natural logarithms, since
$$
\ln(1 - z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} z^n.
$$
After much algebra (which I won't go into here, since this kind of qualifies as a "homework-like question"), this should reduce to the form given in the Jackson exercise.

I'll think a bit more about Question (ii) and see if I can come up with anything.  It's probably worth noting that if the original charge $q$ is at coordinates $(r', \theta')$, then the angular positions of the image charges in the corresponding problem are $\theta', \theta' + 2\alpha, \theta' + 4 \alpha, ... \theta' + 2(k-1)\alpha$ for the positive charges, and $-\theta', -(\theta' + 2\alpha), -(\theta' + 4 \alpha), ... -(\theta' + 2(k-1)\alpha)$ for the negative charges.  This means that (2) can be written as
$$
G(\mathbf r,\mathbf r') = \frac{1}{2} q \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} \ln \left[ \frac{r^2 + (r')^2 - 2 r r' \cos( \theta - (\theta' + n \alpha)) }{r^2 + (r')^2 - 2 r r' \cos( \theta + (\theta' + n \alpha))}\right],
$$
which looks like a step in the right direction, but it's still not clear to me how you'd go from this equation to the form written in the Jackson exercise.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably plenty in terms of getting between the two forms in Jackson, and the work back from the method-of-images result is in the right direction, but there's still some more bridges to build there.

Answer (score 2):

Michael Seifert's answer is basically correct, and I'll just fill in a few steps missing in the answer to Question (ii).

In terms of Jackson's Green function, the potential due to the charge is:
$$V(\mathbf r, \mathbf r') = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}G_{Jackson}(\mathbf r, \mathbf r')$$
To obtain the same result using the method of images, the expression for the Green's function must be properly normalised. The original charge is actually a line charge (in 3D), and so will be the image charges. The potential is therefore the sum of potentials of line charges:
$$V(\textbf r, \textbf r')=-\frac{1}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\sum_{i}q_i\ln(\|\mathbf r- \mathbf r_i\|)$$
Arranging the image charges as suggested by Michael Seifert, that is placing positive charges at locations $\theta'+2n\alpha$ and negative charges at $-(\theta'+2n\alpha)$ for $n = 0, \ldots, k-1$ we obtain the following expression:
$$V(\mathbf r,\mathbf r') = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} \ln \left[ \frac{r^2 + (r')^2 - 2 r r' \cos( \theta + \theta' + 2n \alpha)}{r^2 + (r')^2 - 2 r r' \cos( \theta - \theta' - 2n \alpha) }\right]$$
This differs from the one obtained in the other answer because the normalisation is different, numerator and denominator in the logarithm have been swapped, and we have $2n\alpha$ instead of $n\alpha$ in the argument of the cosine (which was probably only a typo).

At this point, to show that the expression in Jackson and that obtained with the method of image charges agree, it is sufficient to show that:

$$\prod_{n=0}^{k-1} \left[z^2 + 1 - 2 z \cos( \beta + 2n \pi/k)\right]=\left[z^{2k} + 1 - 2 z^k \cos(k\beta)\right]\tag{*}$$
where we've taken $z=r/r'$ and $\beta = \theta +\theta'$. The same proof works for the denominator as well.

Let $u = z e^{i\beta}$ and $v_n = e^{2in\pi/k}$. Then we can write the left hand side of ($*$) as:
$$\prod_{n=0}^{k-1} |u-v_n|^2=\left| \prod_{n=0}^{k-1} (u-v_n) \right|^2=\left| u^k-1 \right|^2$$
which is the expression on the right hand side of ($*$). The second equality follows because the $v_n$ are the $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ roots of unity, so the polynomial in $u$ is cyclotomic.